# check the value from the list against key value from dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare, key-value

I have two data sources, one is a list, the other one is a list of dictionaries.
My data looks like the following:

```
need_placeholder = ['1200', '1300', '1400']
ad_dict = [{"Name": "A", "ID": "1999"}, {"Name": "B", "ID": "1299"}, 
           {"Name": "C", "ID": "1400"}]
```

I need to check if `need_placeholders` items are equal to `ID` value from `ad_dict`. Here is my script:

```
for item in need_placeholder:
    adpoint_key = item 
    for index, my_dict in enumerate(ad_dict):
        if my_dict["ID"] == adpoint_key:
            continue
        else:    
            print(f'No key exists for {adpoint_key}')
```

The output is:

> ```
> No key exists for 1200
> No key exists for 1200
> No key exists for 1200
> No key exists for 1300
> No key exists for 1300
> No key exists for 1300
> ```

My desired output is:

> ```
> No key exists for 1200
> No key exists for 1300
> ```

How can I compare those values without looping through the dictionary or the list?

Comment: I recommend using a class instead of so many dictionaries in a list

Comment: I have to keep the current format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
>>> need_placeholder = ['1200', '1300', '1400']
>>> ad_dict = [{"Name": "A", "ID": "1999"}, {"Name": "B", "ID": "1299"}, 
               {"Name": "C", "ID": "1400"}]
>>> keys={d['ID'] for d in ad_dict} # Set of all unique ID values
>>> [key for key in need_placeholder if not key in keys]
# ['1200', '1300']
```

You can use [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)

```
list(filterfalse(lambda x:x in keys, need_placeholder))
# ['1200', '1300']
```

If you don't care about order

```
set(need_placeholder)-keys
# {'1300', '1200'}
```

Using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
>>> for key in need_placeholder:
...     if all(key != d['ID'] for d in ad_dict):
...         print(f'No key exists for {key}')
...
No key exists for 1200
No key exists for 1300
```

Using [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

```
>>> for key in need_placeholder:
...     for d in ad_dict:
...             if key==d['ID']:
...                     break
...     else:
...             print(f'No key {key}')
...
No key 1200
No key 1300
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your `else` in the wrong place in the loop. That inner loop runs several times for each out one. You can avoid that loop altogether if you pull out your `ID` values first into a set:

```
need_placeholder = ['1200', '1300', '1400']
ad_dict = [{"Name": "A", "ID": "1999"}, {"Name": "B", "ID": "1299"}, {"Name": "C", "ID": "1400"}]

ad_values = set(d['ID'] for d in ad_dict)

for v in need_placeholder:
    if v not in ad_values:
        print(f'no key exits for {v}')
```

Prints:

```
no key exits for 1200
no key exits for 1300
```

If order is not important you can do the whole thing as a single set operation:

```
for v in set(need_placeholder) - ad_values:
    print(f'no key exits for {v}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
allowed_values = {dic["ID"] for dic in ad_dict}

for item in need_placeholder:
    if item not in allowed_values:
        print(f'No key exists for {item}')
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this is by using nested list comprehension

```
[print('No key for {}'.format(x)) for x in need_placeholder if x not in [y['ID'] for y in ad_dict]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in need_placeholder:
    adpoint_key = item
    duplicate_exist = False # flag that will be update if key exists
    for index, my_dict in enumerate(ad_dict):
        if my_dict["ID"] == adpoint_key:
            duplicate_exist = True    # flag is updated as key exists
    not duplicate_exist and print(f'No key exists for {adpoint_key}') # for all non duplicate print function is invoked at the end of inner loop
```